# [JsQR]Cannot access the camera on a mobile from chrome

Tags: mobile, webcam

I am on iPhone and it cannot access the camera from chrome. Is there any solution?

Error Message: "Unable to access video stream (Please make sure you have a webcam enable)"

source code "https://github.com/cozmo/jsQR"

[Demo](https://jsqr-6b35c.firebaseapp.com/) (I copied the same code from Author's demo)

Comment: Your chrome app needs to request permission from the user to use the camera

Comment: How to request ?

Answer (score 0):

This problem solved itself in an update of chrome. FINALLY! Safari is still better because It allows the user to save the setting and it never asks about the camera again for that particular url. Using QR codes in the browsers has allowed me to write "apps" in a browser and avoid the red tape of the big tech app stores.